# How Do I Fix X11 After A Faulty Macports Upgrade?

Tags: macos, x11, macports

Recently, in an attempt to try xmonad (which apparently requires X11 version >= 1.4.6.1), I tried upgrading Snow Leopard's native X11 via Macports. However, after upgrading, X11 has been acting strangely. For example, it won't automatically start quartz-wm (though it lets me do so manually via xterm). It also crashes after being inactive for long periods of time. Checking the console, I get the following errors: [org.macports.startx: No protocol specified]. Further, despite upgrading to X11 v1.9.2, xmonad still doesn't work, giving me the following error:

---

Configuring xmonad-0.9...
    Setup.lhs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
    X11 >=1.4.6.1 (!)

---

At this point, I decided to just give up on xmonad and use the native X11, but this is now giving me the exact same errors. In particular, the native X is telling me that it can't communicate with the display (:0.0) set in the DISPLAY variable (which apparently has been changed by macports' X11 install). Needless to say, this is very frustrating, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Voting to send this to Super User where it should be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts does not upgrade Snow Leopards's X11, it installs a completely separate version of the X11 client libraries and whatever other packages you ask it to.  This is a deliberate design decision with MacPorts and all its packages.  By default and in general, MacPorts installs everything under `/opt/local`.  To not use the MacPorts version, just make sure you do not include any `/opt/local` directories - particularly `/opt/local/bin` - in your shell environment variables - in particular `PATH` - or in any absolute paths to executables and libraries.  If you want to totally remove MacPorts, the following will get rid of just about everything:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/local
```

Comment: While I appreciate the reply, I'd prefer not having to take /opt/local off my PATH, as I use other ports quite extensively. Further, it seems that the X11 port somehow changes the behavior of the native X. For example, opening terminal and typing in "/usr/X11/bin/X" starts X up just fine, except it doesn't trigger quartz-wm (so it doesn't look "Mac-native", so to speak). However, starting X by going to /Applications/Utilities/X11.app triggers the "No protocol found" error, and prevents me from starting up any X apps (including xterm). Hopefully this clarifies the problem a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

The X11 to which the Xmonad error message refers is the *Haskell* package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11/, which doesn't appear to require any particular numerical version of X11 proper *or* of the X server.  In other words, you were barking up the wrong tree.